# Struct Giving Incorrect Output

Tags: c++, struct

When I compile this code, I get an output of 10 when it should be 0.

```
#include <iostream>

struct player
{
    int hp;
    int dmg;
};

void dealdamage(player x, player y)
{
    y.hp = y.hp - x.dmg;
}

int main()
{
player p1, p2;
p1.hp = 10, p1.dmg = 10;
p2.hp = 10, p2.dmg = 10;
dealdamage(p1, p2);
std::cout << p2.hp << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: This is C++ 101.  [Do you have a book?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: No, I'm waiting to get one though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're passing the `player` structs in by value.

When the parameter is passed by value, a copy is made into the called function. So whatever changes you make in the function won't affect the original.

So your statement:

```
y.hp = y.hp - x.dmg;
```

Only affects the local copy of `x` and `y`. Which falls out of scope and is thrown away after the function ends.

The solution is to pass by reference like this:

```
void dealdamage(player &x, player &y){
```

In this case, then changes made to `x` and `y` will be affect the originals.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go read about pointers and references now.